# Python Pandas if df1.col starts with(string), create df2.col with that string?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data export from a rack management software that I need to manipulate and load to a new system.

In the current export (df1) I have a column that includes the acronym of one of the data centers. That is: column "Region" with values in the format "DC_Rack_01".

I created an empty data frame (df2) that I will eventually import into the new system. This df2 will be populated with data from df1 but the fields do not match 1:1. This new data frame (df2) must have a column "site" which must have the acronym "DC" in it (or whatever the name of the other data centers are). I am thinking to do something as stated in the post question (I hope it's not too confusing):

if df1.region starts with("DC"), use "DC" to populate column df2.site

I tried the following code but it returns a boolean True/False, but I want the actual string "DC".

```
blade_netbox['site'] = np.where(blade_original.Region.str.contains('Site_acronym'), 
                            blade_netbox['site'], 'Site_acronym')
```

I am not quite sure how to add tables in the body of the question other than ASCII tables, which I find a little too complicated for this example. I hope that images of my data frames work.

[image: Original data frame]

[image: Resulting data frame]

Comment: You may have to provide sample data, for as it stands we won't be able to reproduce the error.

Comment: I hope this helps to visualize what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a prefix instead of a boolean you could try grabbing them with [.str method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#string-methods) (in case it follows a regular pattern)

e.g.

```
blade_netbox['site'] = blade_original['Region'].str[:2] # first two characters
```

or

```
blade_netbox['site'] = blade_original['Region'].str.split('_').str[0] # first fragment when splitting by underscore
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using regex:

**Code:**

```
import re
df=pd.read_csv('mycsv.csv')
print(df)
site_acronym = 'DC'

df['site'] = df['Region'].apply(lambda x:site_acronym if re.match(f'[${site_acronym}].+', x) else '')
print(df)
```

**Input:**

```
       Region        device
0  DC_Rack_01  blade server
1  DC_Rack_02  blade server
2     Rack_03           NaN
3   RackDC_03           NaN
```

**Output:**

```
       Region        device site
0  DC_Rack_01  blade server   DC
1  DC_Rack_02  blade server   DC
2     Rack_03           NaN     
3   RackDC_03           NaN
```

**Explanation:**

1. `$` to represent start of a string
2. `[]` to say match exact pattern inside the brackets
3. `.` any character except a newline character
4. `+` one or more occurrences of the one-character regular expression, here `.+` means one or more occurrences of any character after the site acronym

**If you want zero or more occurences of any character after the site acronym you can use `.*`**

Answer (score 0):

supposing the `'Site_acronym'` is always the first two letters from the column `'region'` you can try:

```
blade_netbox['site'] = blade_original['Region'].apply(lambda x: x[:2])
```

output:

```
       name        device site
0  device_1  blade server   DC
1  device_2  blade server   DC
```

EDIT:
This only works if both DataFrame have the same length and the rows have same order.